# How to create WebSocket API on AWS with Api Gateway and GO SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-go

Im using [AWS SDK for Go API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api) to create a WebSocket API but when I create the API I can't specify the protocol of type WebSocket

Code that I use to create the resource:

```
package main

import (    
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigateway"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
)

func main() {

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    ))

    apises := apigateway.New(sess)

    data, err := apises.CreateRestApi(&apigateway.CreateRestApiInput{
        Name: aws.String("test-api"),

    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

What I expect :
[image]

What the code creates :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this package: `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigatewayv2`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigatewayv2"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1"),
    },
    ))

    apises := apigatewayv2.New(sess)

    data, err := apises.CreateApi(&apigatewayv2.CreateApiInput{
        Name:         aws.String("test-api"),
        ProtocolType: aws.String(apigatewayv2.ProtocolTypeWebsocket),
        // ...
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

And please note that there is a `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/apigatewayv2` package too. Maybe you want to [migrate to the AWS SDK for Go V2 from AWS SDK for Go V1](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/).

Comment: The response that I get with this code it's this -> { } . a pair of empty curly brackets

Comment: Can you update your answer to describe what you have done? And have you check the error?

Comment: There is no error on the code, the code just return an empty pair of curly brackets - { }

Comment: I was looking into the documentation and I think that CreateApi don't exist, i only see examples with createRestApi

Comment: Please note that the package is [github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigatewayv2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigatewayv2).